# How to go about solving "access to the path is denied asp.net"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, permissions

i have been trough the other entries here on stackoverflow but nowhere is there a step by step way to solve this? is it THAT complicated?

i want to unzip to a folder on my local drive and also get this error. must i do something in my webconfig?

should i just have write access to the whole of my c drive?? that wont be good?

thanks

```
public ActionResult Upload(ScormUploadViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (model.ScormPackageFile != null)
    {
        //string destinationDirectoryName = "c:\\TSFPreview\\Zinc\\Web\\Project\\ScormPackages";
        string zipCurFile = model.ScormPackageFile.FileName;
        //string origZipFileName = zipCurFile.Remove(zipCurFile.Length - model.ScormPackageFile.FileName);
        string destinationDirectoryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipCurFile);
        //Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Testing");
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Testing"); //here get that error
        streamReader.Read();
        using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(model.ScormPackageFile.InputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
          //Decompress.CopyTo("C:\\Testing");
        }
    }
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Ok, now since this is an MVC app, I am guessing this is hosted on IIS. Can you check what app pool identity this application is using? And does that user have permissions to do File IO?

Comment: please help how do i check this? i have no idea sorry

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, hence posting an answer -

Open your IIS, follow the instructions in this [post](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). This tells you how to check for Application pool identity.

By default, the asp.net applications run under an account that has minimum permissions, and are denied rights to write to c:\ location.

Change the application pool identity to use a local account that has the permissions required to create a directory etc. operations that you are attempting. (You could test this by putting your login in the app pool identity, although not recommended for deployed code).

Comment: how do i Open the IIS Management Console?? please

Comment: Go to run and type in 'inetmgr'. Hit Enter. Alternatively, you could also browse - Control Panel  -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services

Comment: i  browsed to administrative tools and dont find IIS in the list?

Comment: Do you have IIS enabled? What happens when you type in 'inetmgr' in run?

Comment: how do i get to run? i dont even know how to do that in win 7?

Comment: Press 'Windows key' + 'R'. This brings up the run console.